# Laravel deployment to VPS server not working

Tags: git, apache, laravel, deployment, vps

First things first: I'm a huge noob with Laravel, Git(hub) and Linux, but I want to get a good workflow so I'm forcing myself to learn to do things right the first time.

Now then. I made a small simple website with Laravel homestead. It's working on my desktop, it's all ready for deployment. I've rented a VPS at OVH and I've used SSH to get into it. I set up apache and I cloned the files to my /var/www/html. However, as you can see on www.somentus.nl, it's not working. Rather than showing the website, all it does is show the folder structure. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help and my apologies for being such a noob :P

*Edit: great, my VPS crashed :D
I'll try out the suggestion of switching to nginx when it's back up, hopefully tomorrow! :)

Comment: Your site is down at the moment. Have you tried setting your `documentRoot` to the `public` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Homestead doesn't use apache, they use a Ubuntu list with a nginx setup. What you're using on your VPS?

You can find [here](https://github.com/laravel/settler/blob/master/scripts/provision.sh) everything that the homestead machine installs.